# How can I display entries in a horizontal table in rails 3.1

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tablelayout, rails-3.1

I would like to display items for an e-commerce page in Rails, and instead of a standard vertical list table, I would like to the title and images from left to right, about 4 across, then continue the list on as added: ie.

Entry 1    Entry 2    Entry 3    Entry 4

Entry 5    Entry 6    ....

My first guess is to make a scope for each column- where I could skip entries by a factor of 4, but I would like to know if there is a better solution using CSS or any other trick?

Comment: unless i'm mistaken, your question is a bit vague. please rephrase.

Comment: @ptriek I think that Darth got it spot on below- was looking for displaying a table of data in an array instead of a list. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a method on Enumerable which is called [`each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice). Basically what it does is give you slices of an array.

```
(1..10).each_slice(3) {|a| p a}
# outputs below
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10]
```

Another option using CSS would be to have a container of fixed width, say 400px, and then have each of the elements have `width: 100px` and `float: left`, so they'll line up one after another.

Comment: Thank you Darth. I will try the each_slice and as a fallback the css. This each_slice works off the controller right? so:

    @products = Product(1...10).each_slice(3) {|a| p a} 

would be the required use?

Comment: @keade It works everywhere, since it's a method on Enumerable and nothing specific to just Rails. You can do it in the controller, or in the view if you need to.