# Ruby on Rails catalog view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone show me or know of a good example that shows how to display data in say a 4 x 3 grid with a pager in Ruby on Rails. The examples I'm finding all display the data in a top down manner. I'm looking for something more like a product grid that I can page through.

Comment: I assume you know about html and css? If yes, then you should specify your question, because this is basic usage.

Comment: Coming from Asp.net I guess I'm looking for something similar to the repeater control.

Comment: Found what I was looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548309/how-can-i-display-entries-in-a-horizontal-table-in-rails-3-1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the pagination railscasts, they are really helpful:

> http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=paginate